# Autocomplete in vscode while using vue cdn

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vue-component

I'm building a project where some parts of the webpage are Vue components. And offcourse I'm using Vscode to develop it. Since this is not a complete Vue app I'm not able to use extensions like `vetur` to autocomplete. I was wondering if there was a way to tell Vscode that `<script>` includes "Vue" code or is there an extension to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is.
Just try working with it that way.
Or better still, work with the `.vue` files in a separate folder and move them to your current working directory when you're done.

Not efficient, but it's the best solution I can think of.